# Google Sheets: Show upcoming dates for certain day of the week

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a weekly budget sheet and I would like to show dates for each upcoming friday for the current month. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may apply `sequence` formula to generate a serial of number for each Friday day and to return all the subsequence date for your budgeting:

```
=arrayformula(date(year(A1),month(A1), 
SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(A1,EOMONTH(A1,0),"D")/7,0)-1,1,DAY(A1)+7,7)))
```

So how does it work:

```
date(year, month, day)
```

Return a new date from the number given by formula

```
ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(A1,EOMONTH(A1,0),"D")/7,0)-1
```

To calculate to total number of remaining week between the current date and end of the month, you can use `Rounddown` but need take remove minus 1 at the back

```
DAY(A1)+7
```

Return the day of next Friday based on the current Friday date

```
SEQUENCE(row,column,start,steps)
```

The `row` value will determine how many counts of value to be populated, which is the number of week from above formula, `start` will be start date of next Friday, and `step` is every 7 days

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Remark:**
You can add the if statement to return blank when the number of remaining week is 0 to prevent the formula return error

```
if((ROUNDUP(DATEDIF(A1,EOMONTH(A1,0),"D")/7,0)-1)=0,""
```